# WebBrowser Use in WPF Not Working Correctly

Tags: c#, html, wpf, xaml

I am attempting to host a `WebBrowser` in my `WPF` application that is going to be used to display a CCTV camera. I have two issues with my current use of it.

Firstly, the `WebBrowser` isn't behaving as I have come to expect with other `WPF` UI elements. I have set it inside a `Grid`, but it doesn't fill to the row / column. It only ends up  looking like this;

[image]

From a normal `WPF` point of view I would have expected the `WebBrowser` to fit the entire host. This is the simple `XAML` for it;

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <WebBrowser x:Name="cctvWB"/>
</Grid>
```

Secondly, it doesn't seem to want to display common web pages such as Google or the BBC, though I believe this may be something to do with my `HTML`, the error message reads *"To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame."*

This is my `HTML`;

```
private void CCTVLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cctvWB.NavigateToString(@"<html>
                                <head>
                                </head>
                                <body>
                                    <iframe src = " + "http://www.bbc.co.uk" + @"></ iframe >
                                </body>
                                <html>");
}
```

Comment: If you want Webbrowser to fill the Grid, why do you define the Grid with 2 rows and 2 columns? And the error is self explanatory, you can't embed that website in a frame. Why don't you use WebBrowser.Navigate('url')?

Answer (score 0):

**To answer you first question**

Just Remove the `RowDefinition` and `ColumnDefinition` from xaml that will make the `WebBrowser` to fill the entire screen.  You have defined the `Grid` with 2 rows and 2 columns, so the control `WebBrowser` inside the Grid by default occupies first column of the first row.

**To anwser your second question**, the publiser of the site doesnot allow you to show their content in `iframe` due to security reasons.  Instead you can try `Navigate` to navigate directly to the URL instead of having it in `iframe`

```
 cctvWB.Navigate(@"http://www.bbc.co.uk");
```